# Can't append list to a list of lists

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to append lists to one list using a for loop, but for some reason, I'm only getting the last value in the list and not all the values.  Here is a snippet from my code:

```py
for n, _ in enumerate(data):
    primary_list = []
    sub_list = data[n]
    primary_list.append(sub_list)
```

Comment: move line 2 to line 1

Comment: thanks for the help!!

Comment: This is one of the strangest use cases for `enumerate` I've ever seen. Using the power of a Python `for` loop by adding `enumerate` just to access the elements with an index is weird. Why not `for sub_list in data:`?

Comment: if you read my question you will see that I said "snippet" of my code. I used enumerate becuz I have conditions (if-else) based on index.

Comment: @cookiesRbad OK, I understand. But using `for n, sub_list in enumerate(data):` still seems better than doing `sub_list = data[n]` in the loop.

Comment: I see what you mean. You spittin!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you can't is because you're defining the list inside the loop. Which means it's gonna be overwritten in every iteration.  Just define it outside the loop.

```py
primary_list = []

for n, _ in enumerate(data):
    sub_list = data[n]
    primary_list.append(sub_list)
```